# A Worthless Piece of Ri-ri-ri-ri-ri-ley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

Disclaimer: Absolutely no offense to @Riley. Sorry if triggered.

---

And now... (music), O.K. Productions proudly presents... the Worthless Ri-ri-ri-ri-ri-ley!

> My head is worth nothing, a piece of flossy wool,
>
> My neck isn't worth anything, just, in a lant'rn, a trifle,
>
> My chest is, with vox, a phrase that means nothing you'd care,
>
> My abdomen is nothing more than a hair,
>
> And my legs turned me into a noun.
>
> If you think I am worth nothing, vote me up, not down!

Comment: A social commentary on Riley puzzles I see. Hmm to upvote or downvote? On one hand it's a good riddle but like OmegaKrypton? Are you worthless? Riley isn't worthless. But Riley puzzles did get out of hand.. hhmmmmmhmmhhmhmmmhm

Comment: Also four people think you're worth nothing. Congrats. I haven't voted, still making up my mind

Comment: @North this is not a social commentary. see the answer and you will know why ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are

> Floccinaucinihilipilification

My head is worth nothing, a piece of flossy wool,

> **Flocci** - plural of [floccus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floccus#English), a flock or tuft of wool

My neck isn't worth anything, just, in a lant'rn, a trifle,

> **Nauci** - a declined form of [naucum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/naucum#Latin), a trifle, something slight or trivial

My chest is, with vox, a phrase that means nothing you'd care,

> **Nihili** - genitive singular of [nihilum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nihilum#Latin) meaning nothing.

My abdomen is nothing more than a hair,

> **Pili** - plural of [pilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilus), a hair-like appendage found on the surface of many bacteria.

And my legs turned me into a noun.

> **Fication** - a suffix which forms nouns of action from verbs ending in *-fy*, e.g, deification, specification.

If you think I am worth nothing, vote me up, not down!

> Floccinaucinihilipilification means the action or habit of estimating somthing as worthless.

Comment: Very nice! I was so sure the second line would be rot13[wnpx (wnpx-b-ynagrea, naq fbzrguvat pna or jbegu wnpx)]...

Comment: nice one, you got it!