# iEnglish word and its secret Puzzle

Tags: word, language, english

Many students pass their A-Levels (UK), High School Degree or their countries' equivalent. Most of them passionately have to study mathematics and in one of their courses, they might have heard:

> [indivisibility](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indivisibility)

Some of them might have noticed: "what a curious word with so many i in it!".

This puzzle is to discover a secret word behind the as best as possible iEnglish word.

#### What is an iEnglish word?

- It's an English word, with the rule that it must exists in a 2019 or earlier English dictionnary.
- an iEnglish word, noted $w$ is associated with a score $s(w)$, which is computed as follows:

  - $n_i(w) = \text{number of letters i in } w$
  - $n_d(w) = \text{number of letters different than i in }w$
  - $s(w) = n_i(w)(n_i(w)+\text{is_prime(}n_d(w)\text{)})$
  - $\text{is_prime(}n_d(w)\text{)}$ helps untie by being equal to one if $n_d(w)$ is prime and 0 otherwise.
  - An example is $s(\text{indivisibility}) = 6(6 + 0) = 36$
- Of course, the best iEnglish word is the one with the highest score!

#### What is a secret word?

Let $w$ be an iEnglish word, a secret word of $w$ has $n_i(w)$ letters but contains no letters of $w$. A secret word of indivisibility can be August.

Comment: I've downvoted this both because the metric being used is arbitrary, and the rule about Wiktionary means the answer is subject to change over time as new words are recognized and added.

Comment: You are right @Deusovi, I tried changing the metric and changing the wikitionnary rule ^^'

Comment: Do you intend for it to be $n_i(w) +$ is_prime(w) or do you really intend for it to be $n_i(w) \times$ is_prime(w)?

Comment: @Adam, I don't know which would be best. Second would surely make the puzzle a search of primary numbers, and indivisibility won't be a good score anymore! I hesitate

Comment: I've finaly choosen a compromise between the two options

Comment: My issue with the first option was that it definitely would've had multiple solutions since all you had to effectively do was maximise $n_i(w)$ which is obviously Duck's answer but is_prime(w) allows any word one i off of Ducks answer with prime amount of other letters to be a solution. With the current formula, it is almost the same deal but masked in more complexity. The issue is that is_prime(w) is too black and white and doesn't sort words too well so it keeps coming back to maximise $n_i(w)$ (which isn't much of a puzzle)

Comment: "No battle plan ever survives contact with the enemy."

Comment: @Adam, thank you for your feedback. I keep tried to improve my question and adding a second part for making it a true puzzle :)

Comment: @RShields, yes it might be a good resume of this question haha

Comment: The community recently decided to [do away with open-ended puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6617/30633). This puzzle bears all the hallmarks of what we mean by “open-ended” — it uses a scoring metric to decide a best-so-far, allows an unbounded set of candidate solutions that is only as limited as the dictionary one elects to use, and neither seeks nor plausibly permits a proof that any proffered answer is demonstrably “best”.  For these reasons I believe we must close it, and am doing so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic: open-ended.

Comment: @J.Khamphousone Have you checked if floccinaucinihilipilification has a secret word? A nine letter word using the letters b, d, e, g, j, k, m, q, r, s, v, w, x, y, and z probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @Duck, Indeed I've noticed that, that's why I added: ”as best as possible iEnglish word". But as Rubio said, this puzzle isn't on-topic for Puzzling anymore :)

Comment: @J.Khamphousone I've made one as best as I could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

> Floccinaucinihilipilification is a word $9(9+0)$ = $81$
> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floccinaucinihilipilification

For the secret word:

> A secret word for indivisibilities is camphor.

Comment: I had to change the formula ;p

Comment: @RShields, you both had the same idea at nearly the same instant, but who will find the second part first? :D

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79198/a-worthless-piece-of-ri-ri-ri-ri-ri-ley what a coincidence +1!

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this word in many, many riddles.

Answer (score 3):

A note:

> **[indivisibilities](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indivisibilities#English)** is a valid word with score $7(7 + 0) = 49$.

Another note, since the formula was changed:

> <s>**[pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)** is a valid word with score $7(7 + 1) = 56$.</s>
>  **[floccinaucinihilipilification](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floccinaucinihilipilification)** is a valid word with score $9(9 + 0) = 81$. I stand corrected.

Another note: the formula got changed again.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! that's a really nice answer providing a great score ;p Can you find better? I +1 you ;)

Comment: I got that before you @RShields. +1

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to change the formula again so the puzzle makes more sense

Comment: Timestamps say the posts were made within the same second @Duck

Comment: Except for the fact that I put floccinaucinihilipilification in a comment even before the new formula came. @RShields

Comment: Edit: and then deleted it so I could make it an answer.

Comment: @Duck, you both had the same idea at nearly the same instant, but who will find the second part first? :D